# Insights from the scatter plot and possible ML model to apply to predict Y value

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, data-science

I have features X1-X6 and predictor variable Y.

My aim to understand the relationship between X1-X6 to Y and then apply ML model to predict the value of Y.

Can you help with what insights you are getting from these plots and what all options I can look for model?

Feature and predictor variables are continuous variables. I ran a correlation matrix as well and there seems to be no linear correlation. What other insights can be observed ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Couple of observations:**

None of your IVs is strongly correlated with your DV.

There is high correlation between few of your IVs, like `x1` and `x6` are highly correlated with each other.

With these variables your model might not be a strong one, you can try [`data transformation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transformation_(statistics)) with the variables and see if it makes some impact on your model.

You could test your model for [`multicollinearity`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) and see if you can remove any of your variables which doesn't contribute in explaining in your DV.